# Error reading from configuration file

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to install mongodb on windows 7 64-bit. I've extracted the files and copied the bin directory to c:\mongodb. Under c:\mongodb I've placed a configuration file, mongod.cfg, whose content is:

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: c:\mongod\data\log\mongod.log
storage:
   dbPath: c:\mongod\data\db
```

I then ran the following command:

```
mongod.exe --config "C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg" --install
```

The result was the following error message:

```
error command line: unrecognized line in 'systemLog:'
```

I tried to save the cfg file as both ANSI and UTF-8 but it didn't seem to matter. I just want mongodb to be aware of my storage and log settings.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB configuration files are expressed using YAML. In YAML, litteral string can be expressed using [double-quoted style](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2787109), [single-quoted style](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788097) or [plain style](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788859) (aka "unquoted").

As your path string contains both `:` *and* `\` you have to use *single-quoted style* here:

```
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: 'c:\mongod\data\log\mongod.log'
storage:
   dbPath: 'c:\mongod\data\db'
```

Comment: I tried with single quotes, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Your answer ended hours of frustration installing MongoDB on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was happening because I had an old db version running and installing the MSI installer didn't upgrade it. When I ran `mongod.exe --version`, it said I was still running an old db version (2.2.2 for me).

I had to...

1. Stop the Mongo Windows Service
2. Go to the [Mongo Download Center page](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community), and click on the **All Version Binaries** link.
3. Download and extract the zip file.
4. Overwrite the Mongo exe files in my install location with the new ones from the zip.
5. Remove the service with `mongod --config C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg --remove`
6. Install the service with `mongod --config C:\mongodb\mongod.cfg --install`

I'm not sure if the MSI didn't know where to install or what, but now `mongod --version` returns the proper version number, and no `error command line: unrecognized line in 'systemLog:'` when installing the service.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the full command `"C:\<install directory>\mongod.exe" --config "C:\<config>" --install` and make your your command prompt is being run as admin.

Answer (score 0):

I expect this is due to the case of the storage option changing during the 3.0 development cycle. In some of the early release candidates the parameter used different case (eg. "wiredtiger") but the canonical config option for the 3.0 final release is "wiredTiger" as per the documentation. Alternate variations were supported for a few successive point releases but eventually removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps someone else: I ran into the same issue and the problem ended up being due to an older version of mongod in my PATH environment variable (instead of the one I expected; probably what @ThrowsException was getting at).